# Android scheduling repeating alarms with broadcast receiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have to send 3 different notification(different content) at different time in a day.
Following the official documentation, https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#type, 
I was able to send notification at specified times, but having some trouble with changing the content of each notification. Following is the method to set notifications and is called in onCreate() method of MainActivity.

```
public void setNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    for (int id = 0; id < 3; id++) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Defining different pendingIntent
        switch (id){
            case 0:
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
                break;
            case 1:
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
                break;
            case 2:
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
                break;
        }
        if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, 0);
        // setRepeating() schedules an alarm
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

I am aware that I can use Intent.putExtra() features to send data, which can be used to identify the intent, but this data will be lost if app is killed.
I want this to work even if app is not running or app gets killed or device is booted. After some reading I found out that I can use a BOOT_COMPLETE listener to set alarms after device is booted. Because of setting notifications in onCreate() method, notification is appearing everytime I run the app, even though I tried to tackle this by using following code

```
if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
```

Currently onReceive method looks like this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("Message");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

I need help in deciding where should I put setNotification() method so that it registers all alarms once and how to identify which intent is coming so that appropriate actions can be taken. One way to go about it is to define 3 different broadcastReceivers with intent filters and set intent URI while creating them. Is it the correct way or is there any other simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to identify which intent is coming so that appropriate actions can
>   be taken

You need to set an action to Intent in order to receive data in BroadcastReceiver

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("THIS_IS_MY_ACTION");
```

**Case of `BOOT_COMPLETE`**

Cancel all the alarm on Boot, and reset them. To cancel an alarm Call `cancel()` on AlarmManager with an same `PendingIntent` which you have used while setting an alarm using `setRepeating()`.

 
Take care of `context` and `INTENT_FLAGS` while working with `AlarmManager`.

Use `getApplicationContext()` for context and Keep records of request_code as they are going to be used while cancelling an alarm, use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

This might help:-

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), request_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Answer (score 1):

> notification is appearing everytime I run the app,

Keep a check using `SharedPreference` and set only once if not done.

Also your code

```
if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

should be somewhat like this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
// Get the current time in millis
long currentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
// Set the reminder times
switch(id) {
    ..
    ..
}
//Get the reminder time in millis
long intendedTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

if (intendedTime < currentTime) {
    // Set from next day and to repeat once a day.
    // you might consider using calendar.add() for adding one day to the current day

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    intendedTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
} else {
    // Set for today and to repeat once a day.
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll modify my code accordingly.